# SSIS varchar(datecol) to Date col conversion

Tags: ssis

Source column is varchar datatype with null values and need to loaded into date column with default values for nulls in the column. SSIS

I tried to convert using REPLACEISNULL but it didn't work.
Please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: From @gleb: 
it would be a good idea to post more info around what you're trying to do - ie how are you performing the conversion, what kind of failure are you seeing and whether the target column is NOT NULLable with a DEFAULT constraint

Comment: There's no REPLACEISNULL function in SSIS. The expression editor lists all available functions, so you can easily find what you did wrong

Answer (score 0):

My first choice would be to use a SQL query for the source, and doing ISNULL() or COALESCE() to replace NULL with a default value.

If you have to do it later in the dataflow, you can use the ternary operator in a Derived Column Transformation:

```
MyColumn == null ? 'default value' : MyColumn
```

And of course, cast the result of the expression as a date datatype.